# In the class, how do i name the output file as the name of the future instance of this class

Tags: python, pandas, class, dataframe, instance

I am a beginner in creating class. In my class, I have defined a function to output a csv file. However, I would like to name the csv file name with the name of the future instance.
Here is a dummy code hopefully can explain what i want ot do

```
class output
     function()
         df.to_csv('output.csv')
a=output()
a.function()
```

The results i am looking for: the output csv file - a.csv
How do i achieve the above?

Comment: You simply code the name to match the variable you use: `df.to_csv('a.csv')`.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  The file doesn't have an obvious relationship to the variable you decided to use in the program.

Comment: Just pass the name of the output file as an argument to `function()` and then inside the function use it in the `df.to_csv()` call.

Comment: @martineau make sense. I was too greedy  trying to do it automatically inside the class defnition. The simplest way is to pass the name when generate an instance. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An appropriate way to code your intent is to pass the name of the csv file (or some portion of it) to the object's constructor:

```
#UNTESTED
class output:
    def __init__(self, myname):
        self.myname = myname
    def function():
         df.to_csv(self.myname + '.csv')

a=output('a')
a.function()
```

There's no useful way to do precisely what you asked for. The name(s) of the variable(s) that are bound to your object are not known by the object itself.

But even if the variable(s)'s name(s) were available, consider this:

```
a=output()
b=a
a.function()
b.function()
```

The two `.function()` calls are happening on precisely the same object. The object wouldn't know whether to create `a.csv` or `b.csv`.

Even worse, what about:

```
lst[4] = dct["hello"] = output()
```

Assuming `.function()` is invoked, what would the filename be?

Comment: `df.to_csv(self.myname + '.csv')`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you describe *is* possible due to Python's extremely dynamic abilities. However, it will be clumsy and most probably not the right way to achieve your goal. Consider simply doing

```
class output:
    def function(name):
        df.to_csv(name + '.csv')

a = output()
a.function('a')
```

Generally speaking, your choice of variable names should never affect the final outcome of your code.

Comment: Though superficially similar, the answer by Robᵩ is better, as the naming information lives on the instance and only has to be provided once in the case of multiple calls to `function`.